# Flutter - Change color of items on select

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to change the color of the selected items from a mapped list. the following code only changes the color of the last item selected but what i want to change all the selected items. Thanks.

```
String selectedSport = '';

Wrap(
       
        children: List1.entries.map<Widget>((entry) {
          return FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 7),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: selectedSport == entry.key? AppColor.blueColor.withOpacity(0.3): Colors.white ,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                        border: Border.all(color: AppColor.blueColor)),
                    child: Center(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {

                              setState(() {
                                selectedSport = entry.key;  
                              }); 
                            },
                            child: Text(entry.key, style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            color: AppColor.blueColor),
                             ),
                             ),
                             ),
                             ),
              );
        
        }).toList(),
      ),

 Map<String, bool> List1 = {
    'Bubble Football ⚽': false,
    'Futsal ': false,
    'Beach Volleyball ': false,
    'Volleyball ': false,
    'Dodgeball ': false,
    'Rugby ': false,
    'American Footbal ': false,
    'Korftbal ': false,
    'Netbal ⚾': false,
     'Padel ⚒': false,
    'Table Tennis ': false,
}
```

This is the result I want:
[image: Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using lists because there are multiple maps to be selected and not just one.

List selected sports=[];

```
    color: selectedSport.contains(entry.key)? 
    AppColor.blueColor.withOpacity(0.3): Colors.white ,
        setState(() {
               selectedSport.add( entry.key);  
        });
```

do upvote if helpful

Comment: thanks man. it work. God bless you